# non-cached RSLs in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, caching, external, rsl

I have a project that is for several customers, the only difference is in the DB, everything else looks the same, except for the main page's text. That is loaded from an external swf file. I created a library, compiled it as an swc, imported it and using it as an RSL. The problem is that if once I've opened the page, and afterwards update the rsl (because changes in the text are needed), than it's already cached by the browser (not the flashplayer's cache but we shouldn't discuss this please!) and the updated swf won't be loaded. If I use it as an external, the page won't even start up (the browser says it's loaded, but it's blank, not even the loading progess bar of flex appear)

```
<local:MainPage includeIn="default" currentState="{MainPageState}" id="Page"
width="100%" height="100%" />
```

this is the code on the main page, if I comment this out, than the whole thing loads, even with the use of the "external" link-type.

If it helps, in the design view, I see the component, but I get a warning for the library:

> Design mode could not load MainPage.swc. It may be incompatible with this SDK, or invalid. (DesignAssetLoader.CompleteTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the rsl-s are not cached (or at least it reloads on updating, which is a good thing!). I'm just used to visual studio, and because I had problems before with the automatic build of flashbuilder, I always use "clean" to rebuild. Unfortunately I didn't save the mxml before and it probably built the last file, that's why the swc was new but didn't see the change...

Comment: RSLs are usually cached until you publish a new version.